# Loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint

Tags: security, ssl, iframe, mixed

I am trying to eliminate mixed content from a forum (https://www.translatum.gr/forum/index.php) but I have a number of forms with insecure endpoints (they can be found in the Translatum tools tab on the left which is called through the "side.html" iframe).

These js files are used to produce the tab effect: tab2.js and jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.4.1.js

Is there a way, to have this tools tab remain there somehow with same functionality, but without triggering the mixed content errors?